# System.TypeLoadException while using HttpPipelinePolicy on Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, azure-blob-storage

I have been trying to use Azure blob storage SDK on Xamarin.IOS. After creating the BlobClientOptions, when I try to AddPolicy() I get the System.TypeLoadException.

This is my code

```
public class AuthTokenHttpPipelinePolicy : HttpPipelinePolicy
 {
     ... All the methods implemented...
 }

blobClientOptions.AddPolicy(policy, HttpPipelinePosition.PerRetry);
```

This the exception that I am getting

```
Caught an exception = System.TypeLoadException: Type AuthTokenHttpPipelinePolicy has invalid vtable method slot 4 with method none
```

I am using this on Xamarin.iOS

Comment: I’m not sure what is causing the problem, but it seems like a runtime related.  Can you please file an issue at https://github.com/mono/mono/issues

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved after updating some of the dependent packages to latest version.